# Tool to find CSS styles available in a webpage

Tags: css

Say I'm embedding a bit of HTML code in an existing website. I'd like to know what CSS classes are already available. Currently I could do this as follows:

1. View the source for the page
2. Search for links that include .css files
3. Browse the contents of those until I find a useful class

That's tedious, and not exhaustive.

What's a better way?

EDIT You can also do this in Chrome:

1. Inspect Element
2. Select "Resources" tab
3. Navigate to Frames/../Stylesheets
4. View contents of individual stylesheets

I guess what I'm looking for is a higher level, interpreted view of the CSS styles available: not simply the contents of the CSS files. So if one style was defined identically in multiple places, I'd only want to see it twice. If two different styles applied to the same element, I'd want to see the two side by side.

Let's assume I can't do this by embedding code.

Comment: Click "Inspect element" in Chrome - that'll show you which CSS classes the existing HTML elements are using

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I'd like to know what *other* CSS classes are available - not only ones on the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Press F12 in Chrome and select a magnifying glass.
In IE it's Also F12 and then select a little arrow.
Firefox has a similar feature or you can download Firebug which is great for web developers.

Answer (score 1):

I think Web Developer plugin for firefox might be help you. You can add it from  [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/).

Answer (score 1):

The W3 CSS validator tool `http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/` will show all available css styles available to a webpage you specify, underneath a list of faulty styles.

Answer (score 0):

copy this code immediately before the closing tag of the page's body :
I got code from here: http://snipplr.com/view/6488/
Tested in Chrome

```
//CODE    
<div id="allclasses" style="text-align:left">
</div>   
<script type="text/javascript">
var allTags = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
var classNames = {};
for (var tg = 0; tg< allTags.length; tg++) {
    var tag = allTags[tg];
    if (tag.className) {
     var classes = tag.className.split(" ");
     for (var cn = 0; cn < classes.length; cn++){
     var cName = classes[cn];
     if (! classNames[cName]) 
         {
       classNames[cName] = true;
     }
   }
    }   
}
var classList = [];
for (var name in classNames) 
    classList.push(name+'<br />');
document.getElementById('allclasses').innerHTML = classList.sort();
</script>
```

Comment: That also lists all CSS styles in use, not all available CSS styles.